# In Php what happens when an object fails to be instantiated?

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation

```
$someClass sc=new SomeClass();
```

What I want to know is what will be in the variable sc if the constructor fails for some reason (like maybe not enough memory). I can' t find a straight answer?

Comment: Nothing, the entire script will fail. Also note that that is not how you declare variables in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor can fail for mainly two reasons:

1. Out of memory; not unique to objects, this causes a fatal error and your script won't continue.
2. An [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) is thrown; your script will stop unless the exception is caught using a 'try-catch' clause.

> ```
> try {
>     $sc = new SomeClass(); // exception is thrown inside the constructor
> } catch (Exception $e) {
>     echo "Yikes, object didn't get created; error = {$e->getMessage()}\n";
> }
> ```

Comment: Be aware that `try...catch` doesn't catch fatal errors, unless you are using PHP 7 and catching the `Throwable` kind of errors.

Answer (score 3):

With your example of memory issue, You get a fatal error and php ceases execution. You never get to the assignment of the varible $sc.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the syntax for object initiation is incorrect, needs to be `$sc = new SomeClass();` And you would get an memory exhaustion error, and variable `$sc` wouldn't be created.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing that happens when any other type of code fails for some reason like not enough memory and such: the PHP runtime issues a fatal error and that's it. Object constructors are not special.